# Persist data to the DB with message queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, grpc

We have a gRPC server that inserts the data into the CockRoachDB and the data is coming from a Spring Boot micro-service.

This is my code to persist in the CRDB database:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class CockroachPersister {

    private static final String X_AMZN_REQUESTID = "x-amzn-RequestId";
    private static final String X_AMZN_RESPONSE = "x-amzn-Response";
    private static final String PUTITEM = "PutItem";
    private static final String GETITEM = "GetItem";
    private static final String DELETEITEM = "DeleteItem";
    private static final String UPDATEITEM = "UpdateItem";



    public  <T extends Message> T save(final String requestBody, final String action, final String tableName) {
        T t = null;
        try {
            List<GRPCMapper> lGRPCMapper = ServiceMapper.getServices(action,tableName);
            for (GRPCMapper grpcMapper : lGRPCMapper) {
                System.out.println("grpcMapper.getClassName() ==> "+grpcMapper.getClassName());
                Class<?> className = Class.forName(grpcMapper.getClassName());
                Class<?> implementedClassType = Class.forName(grpcMapper.getImplementedClass());
                Method userMethod = implementedClassType.getDeclaredMethod(grpcMapper.getServiceName(), className);
                System.out.println("userMethod\t" + userMethod.getName());
                t = (T) userMethod.invoke(null, ProtoUtil.getInstance(requestBody, grpcMapper.getProtoType()));
                System.out.printf("Service => %s row(s) Inserted \n", t.getAllFields().toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return t;

    }

}
```

If the initial insertion failed, I would like to try at least 3 TIMES before we can log the error. How do I implement that?

A solution that use message queue will be also acceptable.

Comment: What happens when insertion fails, will an exception be thrown?

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Comment: @Renis1235 We should eventually send an exception if all 3 tries are failed ultimately.

Comment: @JustinBertram I use a while loop but this solution doesn't seems very good to me.

Comment: A `while` loop (or equivalent) seems like a perfectly reasonable solution to me. Why doesn't that seem "very good" to you?

Comment: @Arefe a do while loop should be more than enough. Use a counter for your failed attempts and break when the counter >= 3

Comment: @Renis1235 I did exactly that